# How to get a GridViewColumn by its header's name in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridviewcolumn, columnheader

To get a column of a `ListView` in WPF we can do

```
((GridView) someListView.View).Columns[index]
```

But how to get a `GridViewColumn` knowing only the name of its header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:
`((GridView) _lvContacts.View).Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => (string) x.Header == "Name");`
Of course, you have to be sure the column's header is only a string (just like in your sample code).